# Tags for paint and painting

Tags: discussion, tags

Scanning the [list of tags](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tags), I found a several that seem quite similar and probably need clearer usage guidance in the form of tag wikis and excerpts:

- [paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint): 3 questions, two about what type of paint to use and one about paint mixing technique
- [painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting): 6 questions, four about existing paintings (?) and two about working with oil paint
- [oil-paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-paint): 6 questions, five about working with oil paint and one shopping question

What's the difference, if any, between the [paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint) and [painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) tags? Should [oil-paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-paint) always come together with one of these tags? Clearer guidance, please!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I see it working, once tag wikis offer better guidance:

[paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paint) should be used when the question is about dealing with paint in a generic way, and not specifically about one type of paint or another, or when the type of paint isn't known. Examples:

- [When mixing paint colours, what is a good technique for ensuring consistent ratios each time a new batch needs to be created?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/18/when-mixing-paint-colours-what-is-a-good-technique-for-ensuring-consistent-rati)
- [What type of paint should I use for stone painting meant for outside](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/407/what-type-of-paint-should-i-use-for-stone-painting-meant-for-outside)

[painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) should be used when asking general questions about the act or process of painting itself (verb form), to specify materials are going to be used for a painting project or existing painting. Or, when the question is about an *existing* painting (noun form).

- [What is the difference between linen and cotton canvas?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-the-difference-between-linen-and-cotton-canvas)

  - Tagged also with [canvas](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canvas), but [canvas](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canvas) on its own could be about [sewing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sewing) or [cutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting) or [clothing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing), so [painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) clearly scopes the question to a specific purpose

[painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) should also be used with specific media tags, if the the question is about the process of painting with that medium, just as you would use [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) + [pencils](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencils) or [drawing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) + [charcoal](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charcoal).

- [How do you fade one color to another with oil paint without getting the mixed color?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-do-you-fade-one-color-to-another-with-oil-paint-without-getting-the-mixed-co)

Specific tags, such as [watercoloring](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watercoloring), [oil-paint](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-paint) and [acrylics](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acrylics) should be used when the question is specifically about working with those materials, as the methods of applying, preserving, mixing, etc. are unique to those mediums. They don't *need* to be used with other tags, as seen here:

- [What is the difference between cheaper oil paints and more expensive ones?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-is-the-difference-between-cheaper-oil-paints-and-more-expensive-ones)

Comment: Yes this feels right. Curious to have a look at some of the tagged questions using those tags currently.

Comment: How does this incorporate existing paintings (e.g., a question about preserving a completed work)?

Comment: @Erica If we're not discussing tags like "preservation", then "painting"  + type of paint/canvas. I meant to add a line about "or maintaining" to the painting section. I'll edit when off mobile